# Why is this Recurrence Relation O(1)?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Rewrote the solved question below for a reference:

Original question:

```
T(n) = 2T(n - 1) - 1, if n > 0
1,                    otherwise
```

1st iteration

```
T(n) = 2T(n - 1) - 1
T(n - 1) = 2T(n - 1 - 1) - 1 
T(n - 1) = 2T(n - 2) - 1
```

2nd iteration

```
T(n) = 2(2T(n - 2) - 1) - 1
T(n) = 4T(n - 2) - 2 - 1
T(n) = 4T(n - 2) - 3
T(n - 2) = 2T(n - 2 - 1) - 1
T(n - 2) = 2T(n - 3) - 1
```

3rd iteration

```
T(n) = 4(2T(n - 3) - 1) - 3
T(n) = 8T(n - 3) - 4 - 3
T(n) = 8T(n - 3) - 7
T(n - 3) = 2T(n - 3 - 1) - 1
T(n - 3) = 2T(n - 4) - 1
```

4th iteration

```
T(n) = 8T(n - 3) - 7
T(n) = 8(2T(n - 4) - 1) - 7
T(n) = 16T(n - 4) - 8 - 7
T(n) = 16T(n - 4) - 15
```

Final table

```
At k=1, T(n) = 2T(n - 1) - 1
At k=2, T(n) = 4T(n - 2) - 3
At k=3, T(n) = 8T(n - 3) - 7
At k=4, T(n) = 16T(n - 4) - 15
        T(n) = 2ᴷT(n - k) - (2ᴷ - 1)
At k=n  T(n) = 2ᴺT(n - n) - (2ᴺ - 1)
        T(n) = 2ᴺT(0) - (2ᴺ - 1)
        T(n) = 2ᴺ - (2ᴺ - 1)
        T(n) = 2ᴺ - 2ᴺ + 1
        T(n) = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inductive proof that T(n) = 1 looks like this:

**Induction start.**

What is T(0)? 1.

**Induction step.**

Assume for any n >= 0 that T(n) = 1. Now let's see if the claim holds for T(n+1).

T(n+1) = 2*T(n) - 1 = 2*1 - 1 = 1

**Conclusion.**

T(n) = 1 for all natural n. And 1 is in O(1).

**Your error.**

The first error I found in your calculation is here:

```
T(n) = 2²(2T(n - 3) - 1) - 3
T(n) = 2³T(n - 3) - 2 - 3
                    ^ this should be a 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
T(n) = 2T(n-1) -1
     = 2(2T(n-2)-1) - 1 = 4T(n-2)-3 = (2^2)T(n-2)-(2^2-1)
     = 2(4T(n-3)-3) - 1 = 8T(n-3)-7 = (2^3)T(n-3)-(2^3-1)
     ...
     = (2^n)T(n-n)-(2^n-1) = (2^n)1 - 2^n + 1 = 1
```